# HTML Touchscreen Gallery Slider

Tags: html

So, me and a few web design friends are working on an interactive kiosk project for our school. Our design team came up with the idea to create a slider consisting of a photo gallery. The thing is the end product should be able to swipe left and right to view the photos.

Now, don't get me wrong, I understand a lot about HTML and CSS, but (due to its touchscreen mechanics) this task seems a bit out of my ball park.

Anyway, if someone could help me out by giving me some examples on how to implement something like this, it would be much obliged. Please and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items:4,
    lazyLoad:true,
    loop:true,
    margin:10
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x450&text=1" data-src-retina="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=1-retina" alt="">
    <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x650&text=2" data-src-retina="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=2-retina" alt="">
  <picture>
      <source class="owl-lazy" media="(min-width: 650px)" data-srcset="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=3-large">
      <source class="owl-lazy" media="(min-width: 350px)" data-srcset="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=3-medium">
      <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=3-fallback" alt="">
  </picture>
    <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=4" alt="">
    <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=5" alt="">
    <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=6" alt="">
    <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=7" alt="">
    <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=8" alt="">
    <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x400&text=9" alt="">
    <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x400&text=10" alt="">
    <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x450&text=11" alt="">
</div>
```

Owl Carousel is jQuery plugin.
Fully Customisable,Touch and Drag Support,Fully Responsive,hardware acceleration with CSS3 Translate3d transitions,CSS2 fallback supported for older browser.
[download link](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/archive/2.3.4.zip)

**Features**

- Infinity Loop
- Center item
- Smart Speed
- Stage Padding
- Item Margin etc,
  [Documents](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2)